# PMOS configured in common gate

Tags: nmos, pmos, common-gate

This is an NMOS configured in common gate:

[image]

I am trying to understand what a PMOS configured in common gate would look like. Would Vin and Vout be reversed in this case? So, would VDD be connected to the same branch as Vin?

Is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: All you have to do is replace NMOS with PMOS (i.e. flip the arrow on the source terminal), then swap \$V_{DD}\$ and ground (and adjust the gate bias as needed). The input voltage is shorted to \$V_{DD}\$ in your diagram, that's not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op's NMOS common-gate circuit is more easily configured for a PMOS transistor by providing a negative voltage at \$V_{DD}\$ instead of positive voltage...(left circuits below). Notice that Vb1 has its polarity switched in the PMOS version.
OP's proposed common-gate circuit is flawed. The PMOS source cannot be connected to a positive DC supply voltage \$V_{DD}\$ and driven by a signal source at the same time. However, if the signal source includes a positive DC offset that can supply PMOS operating current, this configuration *can work*...but a signal source is usually considered to be AC only, having no DC component.
In all these cases, the signal source must withstand the MOSFET's DC source current and still maintain an average voltage across its terminals of zero volts - something that we don't usually expect of a signal source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPyNIw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 The right-most circuit allows Rload to be grounded. However, both Vb and signal source Vin2 are referenced to VDD2, not GND. That's rather awkward in many cases, since signal sources are usually ground-referenced.